# Как эффективнее сравнить корреляцию каждой строчки с другими строчками?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, numpy, статистика

У меня есть набор векторов и нужно сравнить оценку корреляции каждый с каждым и выбрать вектор, с которым лучше всего коррелируют остальные вектора.
Я сделал это способом приведенным ниже, но вижу что это не особенно эффективно. Как бы вы могли это сделать более понятно и эффективнее. Желательно без использования внешних библиотек.

```html
import numpy as np
tmp = []
x1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
x2 = [1, 3, 3, 4, 8]
x3 = [2, 6, 4, 5, 6]
x4 = [2, 1, 2, 3, 4]

y = []
y.extend([x1, x2, x3, x4])

for idx, i in enumerate(y):
  # создаю копию списка, вычленяя элемент сравнения
  a = y.copy() 
  a.remove(i)
  
  # Получаю оценку корреляции 
  for c in a:
    tmp.append(np.corrcoef(i, c)[0, 1])

  print(np.mean(tmp), '\ttmp:', tmp)
  tmp.clear()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы делал это так:

```
import pandas as pd
```

создаем Pandas DataFrame - *столбцы* соответствуют исходным векторам:

```
In [125]: df = pd.DataFrame([x1, x2, x3, x4], index=range(1,5)).T.add_prefix('x')

In [126]: df
Out[126]:
   x1  x2  x3  x4
0   0   1   2   2
1   1   3   6   1
2   2   3   4   2
3   3   4   5   3
4   4   8   6   4
```

считаем корреляцию по Пирсону:

```
In [127]: corr = df.corr()

In [128]: corr
Out[128]:
          x1        x2        x3        x4
x1  1.000000  0.916271  0.661438  0.832050
x2  0.916271  1.000000  0.727267  0.796267
x3  0.661438  0.727267  1.000000  0.235864
x4  0.832050  0.796267  0.235864  1.000000
```

среднее кореляции по столбцам:

```
In [142]: corr.mean()
Out[142]:
x1    0.852440
x2    0.859951
x3    0.656142
x4    0.716045
dtype: float64
```

имя столбца с максимальным средним по корреляции к другим столбцам:

```
In [143]: corr.mean().idxmax()
Out[143]: 'x2'
```

Comment: А могли бы вы пояснить строчку corr.values[tuple([np.arange(len(corr))]*2)] = 0 ? Для меня она не совсем очевидна

Comment: и вот тут: corr.mean()  получается в действительности заниженная корреляция, поскольку столбцов четыре включая и нулевое значение, а знаменатель в нашем случае должен быть равен трем. Нам ведь нет необходимости сравнивать столбец сам с собой.
И тем не менее решение получилось интереснее чем с моими итерациями.

Comment: @Mavar, дополнил ответ